# A question on normal family

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Suppose that the sequence $F_0=\{f(0),f'(0),f''(0),\cdots,f^{(k)}(0),\cdots \}$ is bounded. Show that $F_z=\{f(z),f'(z),f''(z),\cdots,f^{(k)}(z),\cdots \}$ is a normal family.

How can we use $F_0$ to show that $F_z$ is locally bounded. Can anyone hint me an idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Taylor series centered at $0$... triangle inequality... factorial beats $r^n$...

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. I was able to use the Taylor series to show that each element of $F_z$ is bounded.... Thank you a lot!